# How to format pandas styler when column has mixed types?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I was trying to format the pandas dataframe styler object, but the column has the mixed data type and I was unable to format the numbers.

## MWE

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['age',200000,300000.54321],1: ['city',200000,'']},
                  index=['feature','N','mean'])
df
df.style.format({0:".2f”})

                    0       1
feature           age    city
N              200000  200000
mean     300000.54321
```

## Required

```
        0       1
feature age     city
N       200,000 200000
mean    300,000.54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default formatter actually addresses string, float/complex and int separately. So you just need to give the necessary arguments:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['age',200000,300000.54321],1: ['city',200000,'']},
                  index=['feature','N','mean'])
df.style.format(thousands=",", precision=2, subset=[0])

           0    1
feature  age    city
N       200,000 200000
mean    300,000.54
```

Alternatively you can write your own formatter, but this is essentially copying the pandas default formatter:

```py
def func(v):
    if isinstance(v, (float, complex)):
        return "{:,.2f}".format(v)
    elif isinstance(v, int):
        return "{:,.0f}".format(v)
    return v

df.style.format({0: func})
           0    1
feature  age    city
N       200,000 200000
mean    300,000.54
```